# Render conditionally to divs height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within react, I'm trying to render a inner div only if its height doesn't get greater than a given percentage of a outer divs height.

I came up with the following solution:

**Wrapper.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Presentation from "./Presentation"

export default class Wrapper extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { percentage: 0 };

        this.myRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState(
            {percentage: this.myRef.current.inner.clientHeight/this.myRef.current.outer.clientHeight * 100}
        )
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        const percentage = this.myRef.current.inner.clientHeight/this.myRef.current.outer.clientHeight * 100;

        if (prevState.percentage !== this.state.percentage){

            this.setState(
                {percentage: percentage}
            )
        }

    }

    render(){
        return <Presentation ref={this.myRef} percentage={this.state.percentage}>abc</Presentation>
    }
}
```

**Presentation.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';

const Presentation = (props, ref) => {
    const innerRef = useRef();
    const outerRef = useRef();

    const inputRef = useRef();
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        get inner(){
            return innerRef.current
        },
        get outer(){
            return outerRef.current
        }
    }));
    console.log("percentage presentation: ", props.percentage)
    return <div><div ref={outerRef}>Outer<div ref={innerRef}>
        <div>Anteil inner: {props.percentage}</div>
        {props.percentage <= 50 && <div>50 größer</div>}

        </div></div></div>
}


export default forwardRef(Presentation);
```

Unfortunately it results in an error; Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.

After debugging I figured out what went wrong (there is a infinite loop while rendering going on) but I can't figure out how to resolve it by my own. Can anybody give me a hint for a better solution?

Comment: Can yo create a whole example in codepen.io  ? My guess is that your reference to innerRef or outerRef using a global this.MyRef usage is the root cause for your loop. HOwever - without a usage example it would be hard to tell how...

Comment: maybe your parent is changing height due to the child. Try setting maxHeight and overflow: 'hidden' on your parent